# Does an antibiotic that inhibits protein synthesis delay bone generation?

Tags: antibiotics

After removal of a femoral intramedullary nail the bone needs to generate in the intramedullary canal and bone generation to take place at the screw sites. Would an antibiotic which inhibits protein synthesis, such as Clindamycin delay bone generation?

Answer (score 2):

No, this cannot happen, because the ribosomes of prokaryotes (bacteria) and eukaryotes (mammals) are build differently. Ribosomes of [prokaryotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosome#Prokaryotic_ribosomes) consist of two subunits, the so-called 30S and 50S units, while the ribosomes of [eukaryotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosome#Eukaryotic_ribosomes) consist of one 40S and one 60S subunit.

[Clindamycin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clindamycin#Mechanism_of_action) works by inhibiting the 50S subunit of the bacterial ribosome and since inhibition is highly specific and the subunit is not present in mammals there is no inhibition of protein biosynthesis.

Comment: Mitochondrial ribosomes are similar to prokaryotic ribosomes and some antibiotics can [indeed affect them](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.febslet.2005.09.103). However, mitochondria are also "protected" because they are inside the cell. The linked paper also shows that mitochondrial ribosome is sensitive to some antibiotics but resistant to to others. (also [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.immuni.2020.11.001))